# Not able to parse ip address with port

Tags: rust

I am trying to parse this string to a ip address

```
let address = "8.8.8.8:53".parse().unwrap();
```

This snippet is from https://github.com/bluejekyll/trust-dns/tree/main/crates/client#example

I am getting this error

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:15:13
   |
15 |         let address = "8.8.8.8:53".parse().unwrap();
   |             ^^^^^^^
   |
help: consider giving `address` an explicit type
   |
15 |         let address: /* Type */ = "8.8.8.8:53".parse().unwrap();
   |                    ++++++++++++
```

While the following snippet works fine

```
    let address:Ipv4Addr = "8.8.8.8".parse().unwrap();
```

Just wondering is readme is wrong ?

Comment: Please include the full error message, the "help" is usually just a suggestion on how to fix it. Most likely the original example goes on to use `address` in a function call where its exact type can be inferred, removing the need to add the explicit type at the declaration.

Comment: Added the full error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in the README reads as

```rust
let address = "8.8.8.8:53".parse().unwrap();
let conn = UdpClientConnection::new(address).unwrap();
```

Since `UdpClientConnection::new()` takes a `std::net::SocketAddr` as it's argument, the compiler will infer that the type of `adress` has to resolve to this type, that is, using `std::net::SocketAddr`'s implementation of [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/net/enum.SocketAddr.html#impl-FromStr-for-SocketAddr). This why the README works as is.

Change your code to

```
use std::net::SocketAddr;
let address: SocketAddr = "8.8.8.8:53".parse().unwrap();
```

and it should work.